# Python ValueError: x and y must be the same size and X[:, 0] Y[:] not working to save the problem

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a problem where i want to scatter two arrays. My X array is 2 dimensonal and the log thrown an error: ValueError x and y must be the same size.
So i passed X-s first column only(that's where the data are) and it still throws the error.

**My X array:**

```
 [[5.6 2.5 3.9 1.1]
 [7.7 3.  6.1 2.3]
 [6.3 3.3 4.7 1.6]
 [5.5 2.4 3.8 1.1]
 [6.3 2.7 4.9 1.8]
 [6.3 2.8 5.1 1.5]
 [4.9 2.5 4.5 1.7]
 [6.3 2.5 5.  1.9]
 [7.  3.2 4.7 1.4]
 [6.5 3.  5.2 2. ]
 [6.  3.4 4.5 1.6]
 [4.8 3.1 1.6 0.2]
 [5.8 2.7 5.1 1.9]
 [5.6 2.7 4.2 1.3]
 [5.6 2.9 3.6 1.3]
 [5.5 2.5 4.  1.3]
 ...
 [6.7 3.  5.  1.7]
 [5.  3.  1.6 0.2]
 [5.5 2.4 3.7 1. ]
 [6.7 3.1 5.6 2.4]
 [5.8 2.7 5.1 1.9]
 [5.1 3.4 1.5 0.2]
 [6.6 2.9 4.6 1.3]
 [5.6 3.  4.1 1.3]
 [5.9 3.2 4.8 1.8]
 [6.3 2.3 4.4 1.3]
 [5.5 3.5 1.3 0.2]
 [5.1 3.7 1.5 0.4]
 [4.9 3.1 1.5 0.1]
 [6.3 2.9 5.6 1.8]
 [5.8 2.7 4.1 1. ]
 [7.7 3.8 6.7 2.2]
 [4.6 3.2 1.4 0.2]]
```

**My X[:, 0] array:**

```
[5.6 7.7 6.3 5.5 6.3 6.3 4.9 6.3 7.  6.5 6.  4.8 5.8 5.6 5.6 5.5 6.1 7.2
 5.3 4.3 6.4 5.7 5.4 5.7 6.9 4.6 5.9 5.1 4.6 6.2 7.2 5.7 4.8 7.1 6.9 6.5
 6.4 5.1 4.8 6.5 6.7 4.5 6.2 4.9 5.7 6.9 4.4 5.  7.2 5.1 4.4 5.4 5.5 6.8
 7.6 5.1 4.9 5.2 5.7 6.6 5.  5.1 6.4 5.4 7.7 4.9 7.9 6.7 5.2 6.  5.8 7.7
 5.1 4.7 7.4 5.  6.3 5.7 5.8 5.7 6.4 6.7 6.3 6.7 5.  5.5 6.7 5.8 5.1 6.6
 5.6 5.9 6.3 5.5 5.1 4.9 6.3 5.8 7.7 4.6]
```

**My Y array:**

```
[1 2 1 1 2 2 2 2 1 2 1 0 2 1 1 1 1 2 0 0 2 1 0 0 1 0 2 1 0 1 2 1 0 2 2 2 2
 0 0 2 2 0 2 0 2 2 0 0 2 0 0 0 1 2 2 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 2 1 2 1 0 2 0 2 0 0
 2 0 2 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 0 1 2 2 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 2 1 2 0]

plt.scatter(X[:, 0], Y[:], color = "red")
```

Comment: Just use `plt.scatter(X[0], Y[:], color = "red")`.  With the give `X`, ` X[:, 0]` has only one element `[5.6]`.

Comment: What happens when you print `X[:, 0]`?

Comment: Edited: how can i make one big array of X, without subarrays. (from this X[ [ 1, 2, ] , [3, 4] ...] to this  X[1, 2, 3, 4 ... ] )

Comment: Oh God such a big array without commas.

Comment: It is dynamically filled, so I copied from print(array), and that's why there are no commas.